# Azure App service with or without docker

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I have some experience in using azure app services without docker. I did worked on k8 with docker. Now I am seeing an option to deploy containers in azure app services. As per my understanding app services internally use container and orchestration engine. Now someone can explain why this new docker option in azure app services? How it is going to help? When to use this option? Why I should bundle it as docker(extra effort eventhough it trivial)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Azure App Service on Linux (Web App with built-in images)**

The built-in image option running on Linux is an extension of a current Azure App Service offering, catering to developers who want to use FTP or GIT, deploy .NET Core, Node, PHP or Ruby applications to Azure App Service running on Linux

All of the built-in Docker images are open sourced on [GitHub](https://github.com/azure-app-service) and available on [DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/r/appsvc/)

> Now someone can explain why this new docker option in the azure app
> services?

Web App for Containers is catered more **towards developers** who want **to have more control over, not just the code**, but also the *different packages, runtime framework, tooling etc.* that are installed on their containers.

Customers of this offering prefer to package their code and dependencies into containers using various CI/CD systems like **Jenkins, Maven, Travis CI or VSTS, alongside setting up continuous deployment webhooks with App Service**.

This way you can easily deploy and run containerized applications that scale with your business.

> How it is going to help?

- This will make sure that the environment that **you use locally, is
  exactly the same as the one in the cloud**.
- Just **pull container images** from Docker Hub or a private Azure
  Container Registry and Web App for Containers will deploy the containerized app with your preferred dependencies to production in seconds.
- Automate and simplify your container image deployments through
  continuous integration/continuous deployment (CI/CD) capabilities
  with **Docker Hub, Azure Container Registry, and Visual Studio Team
  Services**
- Automatically **scale vertically and horizontally** based on application
  needs. Granular scaling rules are available to handle peaks in
  workload automatically while minimizing costs during off-peak times

> When to use this option?

- If you are so **passionate/familiar** with Docker/container then you can
  use the Azure App service with the container.
- If you are planning to host all your container in **ACS(Azure Container
  Service)/GitHub** Repository then this service might be useful

You can refer to [this blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/webapp-for-containers-overview/) for more details

Comment: Thanks jeyendran. It helped